# Search A Table View

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how I could add a search bar to this table view so it would filter out the data but still push to my detail view controllers. If anyone knows the code to add a search bar to it using Swift I would love to know.

Here is the code.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewLemon: UITableViewController {



let CarMake = ["Apple","Google"]

let CarModel = ["Nasdaq","Nasdaq",]

let CarImage = ["AppleImage","GoogleImage",]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return CarMake.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: CellLemon = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CellLemon

    cell.cellTopLabel.text = CarMake[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellBottom.text = CarModel[indexPath.row]

    let imageName = UIImage(named: CarImage[indexPath.row])

    cell.cellImage.image = imageName



    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
            let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewLemon

            if let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

                let Make = CarMake[indexpath.row] as String
                VC.sentData1 = Make

                let Model = CarModel[indexpath.row] as String
                VC.sentData2 = Model

                let Image = CarImage[indexpath.row] as String
                VC.sentData3 = Image
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var requestList = [Request]()

var requestListConst = [Request]()

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            requestList = searchText.isEmpty ? requestListConst :  requestListConst.filter({(dataString: Request) -> Bool in
                    return (dataString.customerTitle.range(of: searchText) != nil)
    })
        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

this code help to you

this code is example
if this code don't help to you
say to me until write code with your code

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:
http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
    let array = (tableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

It is a iOS 8 guide, but it works with iOS 9 too.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `UISearchController` class which is made exactly for searching data and updating a view controller associated :

> A UISearchController object manages the display of search results based on interactions with a search bar. You use a search controller in tandem with your existing view controllers. When you have a view controller with searchable content, incorporate the search bar of a UISearchController object into your view controller’s interface. When the user interacts with that search bar, the search controller automatically displays a new view controller with the search results that you specify.

This introduction from [UISearchController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/) is quite important, since it explain that when a search bar is used, you actually see a new view controller automatically presented by the search controller.

Don't worry, it isn't that hard to implement : Apple provides a [great example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html) of a tableview with a searchbar, working both on objective-C and Swift, you should check it.